# Add all data in the tooltip of Chart JS

Tags: tooltip, chart.js

I have created a Chart JS 2 graph that have two datasets.

When I hover over a line I get only the current line's data but I want to see the other line's data too.

[image]

How can I add all the data from the specific date in the tooltip?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To add all the data from a specific label (date) in the tooltip, you need to set tooltips [**`mode`**](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/modes.html#interaction-modes) to [**`index`**](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/modes.html#index) in your chart options, like so :

```
options: {
   tooltips: {
      mode: 'index'
   },
   ...
}
```

**ᴅᴇᴍᴏ**

```js
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'line',
   data: {
      labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May'],
      datasets: [{
         label: 'LINE 1',
         data: [3, 1, 4, 2, 5],
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 290, 0.2)',
         borderColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 290, 0.6)'
      }, {
         label: 'LINE 2',
         data: [4, 2, 3, 5, 1],
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 290, 0.1)',
         borderColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 290, 0.6)'
      }]
   },
   options: {
      tooltips: {
         mode: 'index'
      },
      scales: {
         yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               beginAtZero: true
            }
         }]
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="ctx"></canvas>
```

Comment: This response is still good for Charts.Js < version 3. For 3 and onward, its in ```options: { plugins: { tooltip: { mode: 'index',```